# Regular Expression to return filename and extension if there is a realtive path or not

Tags: python, regex

Orginally we were parsing xml files that had the following `href` attribute values:

`href="file.txt"`
Now the `href` attributes can have a relative path:

`href=".../docs/file.txt"`

In either case I need to return just the file name. We had the following python code calling the following regular expression:

`href_pattern = r'href="([^"]*)`

While this worked only the filename was there, with a relative path, it will return that as well.

I know that a regular expression of the form:

`([^\/]*$)`

Will pull the filename only if a relative path is in the value.

My question, as I'm not a regular expression expert, is what is a regular expression that would work in both cases?

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Russ

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exactly answer the question but I suggest you to extract the field as you did in the previous version and then you can extract the filename from that result.

Comment: I had thought of that, and was probably going to do that unless there was a way to put it all in one! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the 2 patterns, making the part before the last `/` optional. Then get the value using a capture group.

```
\bhref="(?:[^"]*\/)?([^"]+)"
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bhref="` A word boundary, then match `href="`
- `(?:[^"]*\/)?` Optionally match any char except `"` and then backtrack to the last occurrence of `/`
- `([^"]+)` Optionally capture 1+ chars other than `"` in **group 1**
- `"` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yrxx6Z/1).

```
import re

pattern = r'\bhref="(?:[^"]*\/)?([^"]+)"'
s = ("href=\".../docs/file.txt\"\n"
            "href=\"file.txt\"")
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['file.txt', 'file.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MK37dc/1)):

```py
import re

test_cases = ['href="../docs/file.txt"', 'href="file.txt"']

for t in test_cases:
    m = re.search(r'href=".*?([^/]+?)"', t)
    if m:
        print(t, m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
href="../docs/file.txt" file.txt
href="file.txt" file.txt
```